# Вставка кода напрямую вместо app:actionLayout

Tags: android, xml

Допустим, я не хочу используя `app:actionLayout`, ссылаться на внешний файл. Как вместо `app:actionLayout` вставить код разметки напрямую в `<item>`?

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:title="@string/item1"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/layout1"  // сюда код layout с произвольным содержимым
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: Это невозможно, я думаю. Тем более, что я не вижу ни одного повода, чтобы не использовать "отдельный файл".

Comment: Просто если приложение большое, то файлов будет уйма. За свой небольшой опыт программирования под android я обнаружил, что чуть ли ни каждый новый гаджет типа менюшки даёт по 2-3 новых файла.

Comment: Называйте их просто правильно, чтобы можно было их легко найти

Answer (score 0):

Можно вставлять элементы в Toolbar и обрабатывать их самостоятельно

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <CustomLayout/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```